# How to re-build a RPM (rpmrebuild) in non-interactive mode?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I need to re-build an RPM using [rpmrebuild](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/) where I need to modify the `Requires:` lines in a spec file.

#### Commands:

```
rpmrebuild --edit-spec --notest-install --package <rpm-name>
Do you want to continue ? (y/N) y
result: <updated-rpm-name>
```

#### Changes in spec file:

Old Spec file generated by `rpmbuild -ba <spec-file>`:

```
Requires: python(abi) = 3.8
```

Once I run rpmrebuild, it opens vi editor, where I need to modify the spec file like this:

```
### Comment out this line
# Requires: python(abi) = 3.8 

### Add this line
Requires: rh-python38
```

#### Issue

How can I do run this in **non-interactive** mode? In other words, I just want to run rpmrebuild **without** opening the file and just specify the changes in command line itself. Something like:

```
rpmrebuild --replace-requires --old-requires=python(abi)=3.8 --new-requires=rh-python38 <rpm-name>
```

I see plugins for rpmrebuild: https://www.mankier.com/1/rpmrebuild#--change-spec-requires

But I am not sure how can I use it here. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

We can use `sed` command to replace and pass it to `--change-spec-requires` as follows:

```
rpmrebuild --change-spec-requires='sed "s/Requires:.*python(abi) = 3.8/Requires: rh-python38/g"' --notest-install --package <rpm-name>
```

This [example](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rpmrebuild) helped me:

```
batch change of version tag

rpmrebuild --change-spec-preamble='sed -e "s/^Version:.*/Version: YourVersion/"' YourPackage
```